# Easy way to created dated subdirectories on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a web service that is able to store user-upload files in S3. The problem is that we want the files stored in "dated directories".

For example, if a user uploads `a.txt` on `12/1/2017 at 9:15am`, the file should look like this in S3:

`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-bucket/uploaded/2017/12/1/9/a.txt`

Does S3 have any API to help us achieving this or do we need to hand-craft this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such API in S3. Think of Amazon S3 as a storage service, not an application or database.

It is the **responsibility of your application** to store the data in the desired naming format -- just like storing data on a disk.

By the way, your naming format could do with some improvement:

- Always expand fields to the correct number of digits (use `01` for January rather than `1`) so that they sort correctly.
- Think about your use-case -- if you will be scanning documents by year, then the `/2017/12/01/09/a.txt` naming format makes sense since you can look in the 2017 directory (not that directories really exist in S3). If not, then simply store it as `/2017-12-01-09-a.txt`.
- Make it very clear which one is month vs day -- the USA is the only country in the world that treats "12/1/2017" as December 1st. The rest of the world reads it as "12 January". Using the format of `2017-12-01` makes it clear that it is 1-December-2017.
- What about naming conflicts? Can only one person upload a file with a given name on a given day? How are you going to differentiate between different users uploading a file with the same name?
- The reality is, **the filename is totally irrelevant** -- your application should use a database to keep track of objects that users
  upload and assign each of them a unique name. When a file is later
  requested, lookup the filename in the database and then provide that
  file. **Do not use S3 filenames as a pseudo-database** where the name
  conveys particular meaning, otherwise you'll often have to rename
  files to add more meaning!

  - Directories don't actually exist in S3 -- they are just part of the filename. So, you can create a file in a given directory just by storing it -- there is no need to pre-create directories.

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 does not provide you with such logic. But it should by fairly easy to use the time information of your application to create such a s3 object key ("path").

Good luck!